# Accessing files on dropbox with client-side Javascript from http only

Tags: javascript, authentication, dropbox

I'm trying to add Dropbox support to my client-side-only Javascript app (http://bbc.godbolt.org/). As best I can tell I can't authenticate without my site being hosted on a secure server.

For a variety of reasons it's tricky for me to get an HTTPS server set up, and as I'm not using server endpoints I don't see why Dropbox/OAuth mandates an https:// source URL.

I can't find any reference to this limitation, but I can't configure a non-HTTPS server in the Dropbox configuration for my app; and without specifying my endpoint the client-side authentication fails.

Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTPS is required by the OAuth 2 spec for good reason... the access token returned at the end of the authorization process is in plain text and could be stolen if not sent over a secure channel.

Comment: I understand this, but as a client-side app I thought this restriction would be lifted. It wasn't clear to me that the token need be transmitted anywhere for client-side: it was "simply" a redirect with the token in the URL hash. The redirect is sent over HTTPS from the login server, but the URL it redirects to need not be secure as the hash part (after the # in the URL) is not sent on.

Comment: I think the issue there is that without HTTPS, it's hard to guarantee that the user is being redirected to the right location and not some malicious server. (Also, the recipient page could be tampered with in transit, e.g. causing it to send the access token elsewhere.) I admit I'm not an expert on this, but the OAuth 2 spec seems clear that the redirect URI must always use TLS.

Comment: However, this sounds like a limitation of the Dropbox client rather than anything else: the OAuth redirect must use TLS, but there's no reason that the redirect _must_ occur on the top-level frame.  For example, from what I can see (in Chrome's inspector) Google's JS client opens up an HTTPS iframe to perform the OAuth request, and (at least on Chrome) tunnels the token back to the parent iframe using `window.postMessage()`.

Comment: Well, dropbox.com doesn't allow framing, so you couldn't quite do this in a frame using Dropbox, but you could certainly have just the receiving URL be served via HTTPS. If `postMessage` from an HTTPS-delivered document to an HTTP-delivered one works, then you can do that with Dropbox too.

Comment: The built-in pop-up auth driver in the JS SDK should basically do this for you. Just make sure the redirect URL you specify there is an HTTPS one.

Comment: But to re-add a word of caution, you really *shouldn't* do this. If your main app (which eventually sees the access token) isn't delivered over HTTP, users of your app are susceptible to losing their access tokens to attackers that manipulate the content of the page.

Comment: Do you mean HTTPS? :). Thanks all, I found a way to get SSL on my site and it seems the path of least resistance and also safer, although I'm still not totally clear on what the attack vector would be. Perhaps someone can follow up with an explanation?

Comment: Ah - no I get it I think -- you mean if the original page isn't HTTP, then you can be trivially MITM'd and thus have someone grab the token. I get it I think. Thanks all - smarx perhaps could you clarify this exact attack in your answer and then I'll accept it.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant "isn't delivered over HTTPS."